# Has IBsonSerializationOptions been removed from the latest C# driver of MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following source code in my C# project, it can be successfully built with mongocsharpdriver version 1.8.3. But after I have upgraded the MongoDB C# driver to 2.0.1, the compile fails with the error indicating that `IBsonSerializationOptions` and `DateTimeSerializationOptions` classes (interfaces) cannot be found, and I also checked all the namespaces in the assembly, and seems that those types were removed from the latest version of MongoDB C# driver.

```
public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
{
    IBsonSerializationOptions options = null;
    switch (memberMap.MemberInfo.MemberType)
    {
       case MemberTypes.Property:
           PropertyInfo propertyInfo = (PropertyInfo)memberMap.MemberInfo;
           if (propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) ||
               propertyInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
               options = new DateTimeSerializationOptions(DateTimeKind.Local);
           break;
       case MemberTypes.Field:
           FieldInfo fieldInfo = (FieldInfo)memberMap.MemberInfo;
           if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(DateTime) ||
               fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(DateTime?))
               options = new DateTimeSerializationOptions(DateTimeKind.Local);
           break;
       default:
           break;
   }
   memberMap.SetSerializationOptions(options);
}
```

My question is, what is the equivalent of these types in latest version of MongoDB C# driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 2.0 version of the C# driver the serialization options have been removed and have become properties of the serializers themselves. Instead of setting the serialization options, you configure a suitably configured serializer and use it.

An implementation of your convention for the 2.0 version of the driver would look like this:

```
public class LocalDateTimeConvention : IMemberMapConvention
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "LocalDateTime"; }
    }

    public void Apply(BsonMemberMap memberMap)
    {
        if (memberMap.MemberType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            var dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Local);
            memberMap.SetSerializer(dateTimeSerializer);
        }
        else if (memberMap.MemberType == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            var dateTimeSerializer = new DateTimeSerializer(DateTimeKind.Local);
            var nullableDateTimeSerializer = new NullableSerializer<DateTime>(dateTimeSerializer);
            memberMap.SetSerializer(nullableDateTimeSerializer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In C# Driver 2.0 you need to implement `IBsonSerializer`

```
public class LocalTimeSerializer : IBsonSerializer
{
    public object Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        return context.Reader.ReadDateTime();
    }

    public void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, object value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteDateTime(((DateTime)value).ToLocalTime().Ticks);
    }

    public Type ValueType { get { return typeof(DateTime); } }
}
```

and you should register serializer

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTime), new LocalTimeSerializer());
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the common practice of setting the serializer in the latest version of the driver.